# JSTL c:if Comparison Failing

Tags: jstl

I am using the following block of code, which is meant to conditionally display a Spring MVC form tag checkbox:

```
        "<c:out value="${contractForm.option}" />"
        <c:if test="${ (contractForm.option == ' 4') || (contractForm.option == ' 5')} ">

            <form:checkbox path="hold" /><form:label path="hold">Hold</form:label>
        </c:if>
```

The "option" field is a 2-character fixed-width field. The `<c:out>` will print " 5", but the `<c:if>` fails. Can anyone help?

Jason

Comment: Use your debugger, or add traces in the Java code to find out what the actual characters are in the option. They're obviously not what you think they are. Printing the integer value helps. I would also refactor the code, because relying on such error-prone magic values is not a good idea.

Comment: I agree on the magic values, but it's a database limitation because of an old schema.

Comment: There is no reason for the database values to traverse all the layers of the application (data access layer, service layer, controller) until the view. The data access layer should transform those fixed-length padded strings into something clearer and safer (like an enum), and vice-versa.

Comment: There's no reason for many of the things this application does, other than me being paid to implement the requirements the customer gave me. In this case, if the possible values of option change, the customer is changing several things in the requirements document.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `<c:choose>` with `<c:when>` blocks worked. Thanks to JB Nizet for tryng to assist.